# blueimp get uploaded file-list with dynamic path

Tags: jquery, file-upload, dynamic, path

I'm abled to upload files with a dynamic path via PHP. But I'm not abled to list uploaded files in the dynamic folder. Maybe jQuery didn't get the dynamic path. But how can I do it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Maybe jQuery didn't get the dynamic path` Maybe. Post your code.

Comment: It is exactly the same code with the default index.html of jQuery File Upload.  For the upload, I only add hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get the solution and I spend time on it. So my solution is using an iframe in a jQuery popup window and integrated in a house made framework.

Step 1 : jQuery popup window

```
<div id="fileuploadbox" title="Add file(s)"></div>
<script>
function fuBox(aFolder,aId)
{
  $( "#fileuploadbox" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: "850px",
  });

  $('#fileuploadbox').html('');
  $('#fileuploadbox').append($('<iframe width=800 height=400 border=0 />').attr('src', 'index.php?module=fileupload&mode=client&folder='+aFolder+'&id='+aId)).dialog('open');

}
</script>
```

In my case, the folder position depends the base folder and the id of the grid row. For exemple folder=article and id=18756, the dynamic upload path is APP_FILE_PATH/article/18756.

Step 2 : iframe page

The iframe page is the same as the index.html of the blueimp jQuery-File-Uploader.

```
<form id="fileupload" action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="module" value="fileupload">
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="server">
  <input type="hidden" name="folder" value="<?php echo $_GET['folder'].'/'.$_GET['id']; ?>/">
```

I concat folder and id in one parameter and sent it all to the server page.

In the bottom, it must comment main.js and make your own code, I did it :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        url: '?module=fileupload&mode=server&folder=<?php echo $_GET['folder']."%2f".$_GET['id'];  ?>%2f'
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
});

</script>
```

This code is based on main.js, I just changed the url and remove the block of github.io. The url is important here, because it uses to delete uploaded files.

Step 3 : Server page

```
    $uploadDir = APP_FILE_PATH."/".$_REQUEST['folder'];
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
      "script_url" => "index.php?module=fileupload&mode=server&folder=".$_REQUEST['folder'],
      "upload_dir" => $uploadDir,
      "download_via_php" => 1,
    ));
```

Mode parameter is used only to distinct the request for iframe front page or server request in my framework.

So this is my solution and it can work for me with my framework, maybe there is a simpler solution, I don't know.